# In C++, how do I operate on values returned by a function that gives a pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, inheritance, virtual

Programming in C++, getting to grips with inheritance. My program makes a class, and then makes a new class that inherits from the first. The first is a vector of doubles, the second a vector of integer coordinates (defined as a structure). Algorithms that worked on the parent class don't work on the child class. 
To fix this, I've been changing some functions in the parent class to use memory addresses rather than values, specifically a square brackets [] operator that returns the value of that entry in the vector (or rather, now returns the address of that entry). Changing later parts of the program to use the value at the address given, rather than expect a value immediately, isn't working and I cannot work out why after extensive googling and note-reading. Examples of relevant parts of code are:

The square brackets operators

```
//access data in vector
double * operator[](int index) { 
  if(index<0) {
    cout<< "Index out of range" << endl;
    throw;
  }
  else if (index>v.size()-1) {
    cout<< "Index out of range" << endl;
    throw;
  }
  double *ptr = &v[index];
  return ptr;
}
//access data in vector (const)     
const double * operator[](int index) const {
  if(index<0) {
    cout<< "Index out of range" << endl;
    throw;
  }
  else if (index>v.size()-1) {
    cout<< "Index out of range" << endl;
    throw;
  }
  const double *ptr = &v[index];
  return ptr;
}
```

and one of the functions that uses the above operator

```
virtual bool comp(int i, int j) {
  if(*v[i]<*v[j]) {
    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

I get an error on the uses of

```
*v[i]<*v[j]
```

saying that the operator of * must be a pointer, but I'm convinced that the square brackets function is returning a pointer.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  "vector of integer coordinates" is-not-a "vector of doubles", so I'm not sure it makes sense to have one inherit from the other.

Comment: Also, please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your compilation error.

Comment: I tried to fix the format of the code, but am not sure of getting it right because it was missing several `}`. Besides, when you `throw`, you have to throw something; you can only use `throw;` by itself inside `catch` clauses, when you want to rethrow the exception caught.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike your strange interface, vector's `[]` returns a reference, not a pointer. So to compare vector elements, you just want `v[i] < v[j]`. (That's assuming that `v` is `std::vector<double>`; your description and other uses of it imply that's the case, but you forgot to include the exact declaration).

By the way, there's no point using `if (...) return true; else return false;` to convert a boolean expression into exactly the same boolean value. `return ...;` is much easier to read. More generally, you should lay your code out to make the structure easy to follow; my brain started to melt figuring out what it was supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! As I described, the v in some cases will be a vector<double>, however a class that inherits from this class will be using vector<integercoordinates> with the coordinates being described by a structure elsewhere. This is why I've had to use pointers instead of just accessing the value in v[index].

Edit: I should add that the integer coordinates are pairs of integers, so every element of the vector is storing a pair of values.